# How to convert SDK to codename one extension

Tags: codenameone

pls I want to convert one ads sdk to codename one extension. How can I go about this? Or is anybody that can help here. The name of the sdk is whitemobisdk. This is their official website http://whitemobi.com/#developers . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [tutorial on porting 3rd party SDK's](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/integrating-3rd-party-native-sdks-part-1.html), it's also covered in [the developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html).

I looked at their site but unfortunately they don't give any information about the contents of their SDK without registration.

Comment: http://whitemobi.com/android-developer/getting-started-with-the-android-sdk

Comment: Sir, you will get the contents of their sdk through that link sir. If you can integrate this sdk to codename one extension. It will really help the codename one users. Thanks sir

Comment: That looks like something that should be relatively easy to add but since you are the only guy to ever ask for itand none of our enterprise (or even pro) developers expressed interest this probably won't be something we'll do.

Comment: Sir, I will be very glad if you can help me with the CN1 library for that sdk. I went through  tutorial on porting 3rd party SDK's, I dont know where to start with it talk of its implementation. I need your help here. if you dont want it to show to the public my email is oluwasegun277@gmail.com. CN1 is my best mobile apps development platform. Thanks Sir.

Comment: That would be unfair to our enterprise grade developers who pay a lot for exactly this type of prioritization.